# PyTorch classifier for simple images of letters: CNN model design questions

Tags: python, pytorch, conv-neural-network, classification, ocr

Looking for tips on building a simple image classifier for CAPTCHA images of text where there are only two possible fonts per letter. Here's an example image:

[image: full sample image]

Approach thus far has been to try to break up the image into 6 equal-size images to try to get individual character images, and build a classifier for these (example below).

[image: partitioned sample images]

Is there a simpler way to go about this? Any tips on how to design the actual model? (A relatively simple CNN should suffice here perhaps?)

**Edit**: questions on building a suitable model below.

I've tried to build a cursory model on top of resnet50 to subpar effect... this seems like the kind of image classification task that should be relatively trivial.

Any tips on model design greatly appreciated.

Code below:

```
model = models.resnet50(pretrained=True)

for param in model.parameters():
    param.requires_grad = False
    
model.fc = nn.Sequential(nn.Linear(2048, 512),
                                 nn.ReLU(),
                                 nn.Dropout(0.2),
                                 nn.Linear(512, 26),
                                 nn.LogSoftmax(dim=1))
criterion = nn.NLLLoss()
optimizer = optim.Adam(model.fc.parameters(), lr=0.003)
model.to(device)

epochs = 10
steps = 0
running_loss = 0
print_every = 10
train_losses, test_losses = [], []
for epoch in range(epochs):
    for inputs, labels in train_loader:
        steps += 1
        inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
        optimizer.zero_grad()
        logps = model.forward(inputs)
        loss = criterion(logps, labels)
        loss.backward()
        optimizer.step()
        running_loss += loss.item()
        
        if steps % print_every == 0:
            test_loss = 0
            accuracy = 0
            model.eval()
            with torch.no_grad():
                for inputs, labels in val_loader:
                    inputs, labels = inputs.to(device), labels.to(device)
                    logps = model.forward(inputs)
                    batch_loss = criterion(logps, labels)
                    test_loss += batch_loss.item()
                    
                    ps = torch.exp(logps)
                    top_p, top_class = ps.topk(1, dim=1)
                    equals = top_class == labels.view(*top_class.shape)
                    accuracy += torch.mean(equals.type(torch.FloatTensor)).item()
            train_losses.append(running_loss/len(train_loader))
            test_losses.append(test_loss/len(val_loader))                    
            print(f"Epoch {epoch+1}/{epochs}.. "
                  f"Train loss: {running_loss/print_every:.3f}.. "
                  f"Test loss: {test_loss/len(val_loader):.3f}.. "
                  f"Test accuracy: {accuracy/len(val_loader):.3f}")
            running_loss = 0
            model.train()
```

Results from the above look as follows, hitting <50% accuracy:

[image: model results]

Comment: Your approach sounds solid - splitting it into two tasks:

1. Image segmentation - identify characters.
2. Classification - classify character images.

Trying a simple CNN initially is fine, if its performance is unsatisfactory then you can try more complex models.